# Open link Website from button on Wearable Sam sung Watch by code C#

Tags: c#, xaml, webbrowser-control, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I have tried some common ways in C# Programming Language but can't open a web link from Button on the Wearable Device (Tizen Samsung Watch) Browser is Samsung Browser, Looking forward to your support and suggestions

Thank you very much

I have try some command

- Device.OpenUri(new Uri(url))
- OpenWebCommand = new Command(async () => await Browser.OpenAsync()
- Linked XAML ...

But it still don't work

Please give some recommends

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks you so much

I have  try one day and I can solve it by using method OpenWebCommand = new Command(async () => await Browser.OpenAsync() but need to give permission to the samsung watch to launch the sam sung browser

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you so much I have try one day and I can solve it by using method OpenWebCommand = new Command(async () => await Browser.OpenAsync() but need to give permission to the samsung watch to launch the sam sung

Rgds
LĐT

Comment: Wellcome to Stackoverflow! There is no need to thank the answer, if you want you can leave a comment on the answer that helped you